# Different views for spinner and spinner item?

Tags: android, view, spinner

Is there any way I can set a different view for the closed spinner view and the spinner item view?

I assume that the resource id used in the `ArrayAdapter` would be used for the closed item view, as well as the item views, so I extended the `ArrayAdapter` and defined the `getView` which uses a different resource, but the resource id in the call to the super constructor doesn't seem to be used ever, only the resource id used in `getView` seems to be used

In the [Spinner.java code](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/widget/SpinnerAdapter.java&l=1) it states:

> A spinner adapter allows to define two different views: one that shows the data in the spinner itself and one that shows the data in the drop down list when the spinner is pressed.

but it doesn't seem possible given the code.

Anyway - my code:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter <T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    int itemViewResourceId;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewPopulator<T> viewPopulator;
    private List<T> objects;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int itemViewResourceId, ViewPopulator<T> viewPopulator, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.viewPopulator = viewPopulator;
        this.itemViewResourceId = itemViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            // new view - populate 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(itemViewResourceId, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(new Object());
        }
        viewPopulator.populateView(position, convertView, parent, objects.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}

public abstract class ViewPopulator<T> {
    public abstract void populateView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, T item);
}
```

called with:

```
CustomArrayAdapter<T> typeAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<T>(context, R.layout.list_item, R.layout.list_item_big, new ViewPopulator<T>() {
        @Override
        public void populateView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, T item) {
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item)).setText(position + " - " + item.getName());
        }
    }, itemsByType.get(type));
```

** EDIT **

The resource id used is the `itemViewResourceId` defined in the `getView` method - 
adding a new method to `CustomArrayAdapter`, overriding `getDropDownView` as below give me the same results of the `itemViewResourceId` being used for all the styling, and the `textViewResourceId` not being used at all.  However, removing the `getView` results in the `textViewResourceId` being used - hence I don't think that `getDropDownView` actually does anything:

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            // new view - populate 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(itemViewResourceId, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(new Object());
        }
        viewPopulator.populateView(position, convertView, parent, objects.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: getDropDownView from interface SpinnerAdapter ??

Comment: I looked at the code and it seems getDropDownView is never called. I think the important code is in AbsSpinner that is using getView so I am very confused. Android is like the famous swiss cheese, full of holes.

Comment: im trying to figure this out myself. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 20):

If you implement `SpinnerAdapter` does that help?
The following code works for me:

```
private class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
        String[] values;
        Context context;

        public NumberSpinnerAdapter(String[] values) {
            this.values = values;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return values[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, The point is to override the default implementation of getDropDownView of BaseAdapter. Otherwise it calls getView.

Comment: note that we need to provide item for collapsed spinner in `getView` and item for dropdown in `getDropDownView`

Comment: also there is no need to implement `SpinnerAdapter` explicitly because `BaseAdapter` does it

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an old question, I stumbled upon trying to solve the same problem.
I use `setDropDownViewResource`:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);

myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. When creating the ArrayAdapter, provide the view you'd like to show for the selected item. When calling `setDropDownViewResource`, provide the layout you'd like for populating dropdown list items.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, getting different `View`s for expanded (opened) and collapsed (closed) `Spinner` is as simple as overriding `getView` and `getDropdownView` methods of your adapter.

**`getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`** will produce all the `View`s that will be used to display a selected item when the `Spinner` is collapsed.

**`getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`** gets called when you click on a `Spinner` to expand it and display a *dropdown* list of your items. You can either call `getView` from this method (if your items in expanded and collapsed states are similar), or produce a different `View` for the item in your dropdown list.

It would be nice if you override **both** these methods anyway (even if your `getDropdownView` just calls `getView` with the same arguments). And do not forget to use your `convertView` parameter - it is here for a purpose of optimisation (*to reuse existing Views instead of inflating/creating them every time*):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ...
     if(convertView == null){
          convertView = View.inflate(getContext(),
                R.layout.dropdown_category_color, null);
     }
     //...do your stuff with your View

     return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomArrayAdapter<T> typeAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<T>(context, R.layout.list_item, R.layout.list_item_big, new ViewPopulator<T>() {

        @Override
        public void populateView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, T item) {
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item)).setText(position + " - " + item.getName());
        }
}, itemsByType.get(type));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//1---------------
package testing;

public class SpinnerItemAdapterData {

    public int id ;
    public String name;

    public SpinnerItemAdapterData(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
//-------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers are generally discouraged. Could you elaborate on you answer?

Comment: A simple POJO will certainly not solve that problem.